# How to get non-integer value from <p:slider>

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, slider

I am trying to get **Float** value from primefaces slider. But, it seems does't support Non Integer value.

I have try by setting `step - attribute`, no improvement.

**Here is my JSF code:**

```
<h:panelGrid>
    <h:panelGrid columns="2" style="margin-bottom:10px">
    <p:outputLabel value="Interest Rate : "/>
    <p:inputText id="intVal" value="#{primeSlider.interest}">
      <f:convertNumber minFractionDigits="2" />
    </p:inputText>

    </h:panelGrid>  

    <p:slider id="interestSlider" for="intVal" minValue="5" maxValue="25" step="1" style="width:500px;" />
</h:panelGrid>
```

It is possible to get `Non-Integer` value like `float,double` from primefaces slider?

If so, How to do that?

Comment: I've found this issue suggesting that float values are supported since version 2.2. https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=1394. Is that a bug in new version or they simply removed it?

Comment: i have seen that., it seems they removed it.!! But, i am not sure. we should clarify with any of primefaces team member. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not that complicated to handle the slider yourself. Check this sample code:

```
<h:form id="form">          
    <h:panelGrid>
        <p:inputText id="intVal" value="#{primeSlider.interest}" widgetVar="iVar">
            <f:convertNumber minFractionDigits="2" />
        </p:inputText>
        <div id="slider"></div>
        <script>
            $(function() {
                jQuery("#slider").slider({
                    range: "min",
                    value: 37,
                    step: 0.25,
                    min: 1,
                    max: 700,
                    slide: function(event, ui) {
                        jQuery(iVar.jqId).val(ui.value);
                    }
                });
                jQuery(iVar.jqId).val(jQuery("#slider").slider("value"));
            });
        </script>

        <p:commandButton value="Send" />
    </h:panelGrid>
    <p:outputPanel autoUpdate="true">
        #{primeSlider.interest}
    </p:outputPanel>
</h:form>
```

Comment: Yeah., This Jquery helps me... :)